# Routes with optional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Following attempt seems to be functional, but is not the 'clean' result that I am trying to archive.

Following route

```
get "/learn(/:category)", to: "users#index", as: "learn"
```

Should be useable for something like *"/learn/technology"* - Which works, if entered manually in the address bar.

If I tough try to achieve similar in my views, I get the following: *"/learn?category=technology"* - Which well, technically works, but is not what I want.

I'm using the following inside my view:

```
- Category.promoted.limit(7).each do |category|
  %li.category-button
    = link_to learn_path(category) do
      = button_tag "", :class => "#{category.name}"
      = content_tag(:span, category.to_s, :class => 'category-head')
```

And my Category Model looks the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills

  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  scope :promoted, lambda { where(:promoted => true) }

  def to_s
    read_attribute(:name).titleize
  end

  def to_param
    name.parameterize
  end
end
```

How would I achieve the 'cleaner' solution?

Edit:

Following works - but there must be a better solution than that?

```
get "/learn", to: "users#index", as: "learn"  
get "/learn/:category", to: "users#index", as: "filter_learn"
```

Comment: Is their another route called learn?

Comment: No - there is not. The Edit shows how it works again, 'technically'. But I think there musst be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your link to the following:

```
...
= link_to learn_path(category: category.name) do
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [url_for](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for&ei=SqWEUsi8NsTw4gTu5YBA&usg=AFQjCNHskIyPtx2AjheIy-MK70F2NaTswQ&sig2=uGPmJ2U3e94bN9YNxu1eNA) to solve the problem.

Suppose I have `UsersController` with `index` action and this in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get ':kind', :to => 'users#index'
  end
end
```

Then when I'm on /users page I can use the `url_for` this way:

```
= link_to 'Kind1', url_for(kind: :students)
```

which will produce path:

```
/users/students
```

If I'm on some another page (another controller or another action), then I shoud provide more info. For example when I'm on another controller's page then I should provide both `controller` and `action` params if target action is not `index` (if target action is `index` then it is sufficient to provide only `controller`):

```
= link_to 'Kind1', url_for(controller: :users, action: :index, kind: :students)
```

it produces the same path:

```
/users/students
```

While using `users_path(kind: :students)` you'll get:

```
/users?kind=students
```